# Getting a Coursera deeplearning spelization error

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

```
def convolutional_model(input_shape):
    """
    Implements the forward propagation for the model:
    CONV2D -> RELU -> MAXPOOL -> CONV2D -> RELU -> MAXPOOL -> FLATTEN -> DENSE
    
    Note that for simplicity and grading purposes, you'll hard-code some values
    such as the stride and kernel (filter) sizes. 
    Normally, functions should take these values as function parameters.
    
    Arguments:
    input_img -- input dataset, of shape (input_shape)

    Returns:
    model -- TF Keras model (object containing the information for the entire training process) 
    """

    input_img = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)

    # YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
    
    ## CONV2D: 8 filters 4x4, stride of 1, padding 'SAME'
    Z1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(4,4), stride=(1,1), padding='same')
    ## RELU
    A1 = tf.keras.layers.ReLU(Z1)
    ## MAXPOOL: window 8x8, stride 8, padding 'SAME'
    P1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(8, 8), strides =(8,8), padding='same')
    ## CONV2D: 16 filters 2x2, stride 1, padding 'SAME'
    Z2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(2,2),strides =(1,1), padding='same')
    ## RELU
    A2 = tf.Keras.layers.ReLU(Z2)
    ## MAXPOOL: window 4x4, stride 4, padding 'SAME'
    P2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(4, 4), strides =(4,4), padding='same')
    ## FLATTEN
    F = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(P2)
    ## Dense layer
    ## 6 neurons in output layer. Hint: one of the arguments should be "activation='softmax'" 
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')
    
    # YOUR CODE ENDS HERE
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=outputs)
    return model
```

The error is:

`<ipython-input-64-40a674a512e2> in convolutional_model(input_shape) 24 Z1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(4,4), strides=(1,1), padding='same') 25 ## RELU ---> 26 A1 = tf.keras.layers.ReLU(Z1, max_value=None) 27 ## MAXPOOL: window 8x8, stride 8, padding 'SAME' 28 P1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(8, 8), strides =(8,8), padding='same') TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'max_value'`